How does $ \omega_1 $ change between our adoption and rejection of the Continuum Hypothesis?
I recently learned about the topic of inaccessible ordinals and how they can be used to define inaccessible cardinals, which I previously saw without finding a direct correlation in set theory.
What piqued my curiosity is that if we adopt Cantor's Continuum Hypothesis (CH), we can say that $ \omega_1 $ (the first uncountable ordinal) is the same as $ 2^{\aleph_0} $(the cardinality of the set of real numbers). If we reject CH, the cardinality of $ \omega_1 $ would change to become smaller than $ 2^{\aleph_0} $. As far as I understand, the cardinality of the set of real numbers doesn't change in either model, whether we adopt or reject CH, since the way it is defined and the sets we start from in forming it are the same in both models.
So, what strikes me as odd is how $ \omega_1 $ can change between both models and what is the mechanism within CH that allows for this change.

The definition of $\aleph_1$ is the cardinality of $\omega_1$. It is not the cardinality of the reals (unless the continuum hypothesis is true). The cardinality of the reals is denoted $2^{\aleph_0}$.

@AlexKruckman Thank you for the clarification. I've taken your comment into consideration and modified the question accordingly.

The definition of $\omega_1$ and $\aleph_1$ is the same in all models as well (as is the case with any definition in ZFC... definitions have nothing to do with specific models). What is different between models is the relationship between $2^{\aleph_0}$ and $\aleph_1.$ $\omega_1$ is defined as the least uncountable ordinal. $\mathbb R$ is defined as the set of all subsets of the least infinite ordinal $\omega$ (or more typically a more structural definition that can be put in bijection with that set). CH holds iff there is a bijection $\omega_1\to \mathbb R.$

@spaceisdarkgreen Thank you for your comment, which provided a new definition for me regarding the verification of CH. However, I still could not see how adopting or rejecting CH contributes to changing the size of $\omega_1$ Do you have anything that addresses this point, please?

@BezinaTaki The size of a set $x$ is defined to be the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that there is a bijection $x\to \alpha.$ The size of $\omega_1$ is always $\omega_1$ (denoted $\aleph_1$ when we're thinking about it as a cardinal). It's the size of the reals that varies according to the continuum hypothesis. The CH says $|\mathbb R| = \aleph_1=\omega_1,$ and if the CH fails then $|\mathbb R|$ is some larger ordinal.

@BezinaTaki At the level of models, what happens in the most common method (forcing extensions), is that we can go from a model of CH to a model of not CH by extending the model by adding more reals than can be put into one-to-one correspondence with $\omega_1$ (while not adding any bijections $\omega\to \omega_1$ so that the $\omega_1$ of the starting model is still $\omega_1$ in the extension). And we can go the other way from notCH to CH by extending the model, adding a bijection $\mathbb R \to \omega_1$ while not adding any new reals (and again not any new bijections $\omega\to \omega_1$).

@BezinaTaki But I think it's first most important to understand what CH /not CH means (in a fixed model), as in the first comment, before trying to understand the mechanics of how it can change between models, which is a much more technical undertaking, that I can't really do justice to in a single comment/answer.
